# Set variable primal status in Julia JuMP optimization

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

When I try to set the `MOI.VariablePrimalStart` for my JuMP model using the Gurobi solver, I get this error

> LoadError: `MathOptInterface.SetAttributeNotAllowed{MathOptInterface.VariablePrimalStart}`: Setting attribute `MathOptInterface.VariablePrimalStart()` cannot be performed. You may want to use a `CachingOptimizer` in `AUTOMATIC` mode or you may need to call `reset_optimizer` before doing this operation if the `CachingOptimizer` is in `MANUAL` mode.

I tried to `reset_optimizer` as it suggested but it says it is not defined.

```
@variable(m, z[1:n_products], Bin)

JuMP.reset_optimizer()
for i in 1:n_products
    MOI.set(m, MOI.VariablePrimalStart(), z[i], prev_solution[i])
end
#@objective(m, Max, sum((p-c)*(x+xx))-sum(q*u/2)+sum(q*a*xx))
@objective(m, Max, ((p-c)'*(x+xx)-((p-s)./(b-a))'*(u/2)))#-a.*xx)))
```

I want to warm start the value for the z in the optimization since I solve a very similar problem in a previous example.